# Javascript, countdown timer and display text

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a countdown timer with JavaScript.

Here is my script.

```
var seconds_left = 10;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('timer_div').innerHTML = --seconds_left;

    if (seconds_left <= 0)
    {
        //When it gets to 0 second, I want to show 'You are Ready!' text message.

    }
}, 1000);
```

It starts to count from 10 seconds.

I want to eliminate seconds when it gets 0 second and show a 'You are Ready!' message.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
var seconds_left = 10;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('timer_div').innerHTML = --seconds_left;

    if (seconds_left <= 0)
    {
        document.getElementById('timer_div').innerHTML = 'You are ready';
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Here is the [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/PKWXw/)

Comment: Almost.. you have to pass the key to `clearInterval` method (it won't clear all intervals, if that's what you think). See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/PKWXw/) test case.

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById('timer_div').innerHTML = "You are Ready!";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    TargetDate = "12/31/2020 5:00 AM";
    DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.";
    FinishMessage = "It is finally here!";
</script>
<script src="//scripts.hashemian.com/js/countdown.js"></script>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may answer the question, it doesn't provide any context to explain how or why. Consider adding a sentence or two to explain your answer.