# How to set a countdown when user clicks on a link?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, countdown

I came across a scenario where i need a countdown to start after the user clicks on a link, though the number "10" (is a ten second countdown) has to be visible before that. The link itself also opens another page. The countdown its not supposed to do anything at the end, is just decoration. How do I pull this off?

```
<div id="gatewayDimmer">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="gatewaydiv">
<ul id="OfferList">
    <h1>Ayudanos a mantener la P&aacute;gina</h1>
    <span id="gatewayMessage">Hicimos esta p&aacute;gina de onda. Y no se mantiene sola! Ayudanos clickeando en la publicidad.</span>   <br />
    <br />
    <li><a href="http://www.wachahost.com" class="offerlink" target="blank">Cheap Web Hosting</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://peerfly.com/x/0/1076/3696/" class="offerlink" target="blank">Free Apple Ipad</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com" class="offerlink" target="blank">Google</a></li>
</ul>
<br />
<br />
Luego de completar la oferta espera: <span id="count">10</span> segundos               <script type="text/javascript">

            {

            (function countDown(){
              var counter = 10;

              setInterval(function countDown() {
                counter--;
                if (counter >= 0) {
                  span = document.getElementById("count");
                  span.innerHTML = counter;
                }
                // Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
                if (counter === 0) {
                //    alert('this is where it happens');
                    clearInterval(counter);
                }

              }, 1000);

            })();

            }

            </script>            para acceder a la p&aacute;gina.<br />
Gracias!</div>
```

Message script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script type="text/javascript">

    var Delay = 10;

    function setupgateway()
    {
        var Left = $(window).width() /2;
        Left = Left - $('#gatewaydiv').width()/2;

        var Top = $(window).height() /2;
        Top = Top - $('#gatewaydiv').height()/2;

        $('#gatewaydiv').css('top', Top+'px').css('left', Left+'px').css('display', 'inline');
        $('#gatewayDimmer').width($('html').width());
        $('#gatewayDimmer').height($('html').height());
        $('#gatewayDimmer').css('display','block');
    }

    function removegateway()
    {
        $('#gatewaydiv').css('display', 'none');
        $('#gatewayDimmer').css('display','none');
    }

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.offerlink').click(function()
        {
            setTimeout('removegateway()', Delay*1000);
        });

        setupgateway();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript, countdown timer and display text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989285/javascript-countdown-timer-and-display-text)

Comment: No, no. I don't want a text to be shown at the end. Is just the countdown. Plus, it need to be start after a link is clicked.

Comment: Countdown to what? If I'ts not visible and it does nothing at the end, then what is the use of a countdown?

Comment: @Tomás Please provide the HTML/JS which you have tried so far.

Comment: When the page loads, a message pops up. To close it you need to click on the a link. When you do that, the message goes away after 10 seconds by itself. The countdown is just for the warning for the user.

Comment: Well, use a onclick event to call a function, in that function use `setTimeout` to call another function after 10 seconds and in that function close the message.

Comment: I already did that (second code snippet), the problem is I don't know how to hold the countdown until the user clicks on the link.

Answer (score 1):

Try using jquery function :

```
jQuery(function($){
   $('#startClock').on('click', doCount);
});

function doCount(){
   var counter = 5;
   setInterval(function() {
      counter--;
      if (counter >= 0) {
         span = document.getElementById("count");
         span.innerHTML = counter;
      }
      if (counter === 0) {
        alert('sorry, out of time');
        clearInterval(counter);
      }
   }, 1000);
}
```

Demo Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6nDYd/12/

Comment: Just set your counter to 10 instead of 5

Comment: I'm sorry, I know this is going to sound like a dumb question but how do I connect the link(e.g. "<a href="http://www.google.com" class="offerlink" target="blank">Google</a>") with the code? (Thank you so much for answering and sorry again).

Comment: replace : alert('sorry, out of time'); with : window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';